# C decompress Bitmask source

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

This may be somewhat of an odd question as well as my first one ever on this site and a pretty complicated thing to ask basically I have this decompresser for a very specific archived file, I barely understand this but from what i can grasp its some sort of "bit mask" it reads the first 2 bytes out of target file, and stores them as a sequence.

The first for loop is where I get confused

Say for arguments sake mask is 2 bytes `10 04`, or 1040(decimal) thats what it usually is in these files

```
    for (t = 0; t<16; t++) {
        if (mask & (1 << (15 - t))) {
```

This seems to be looping through all 16 bits of those 2 bytes and running an AND operation on mask (1040) on every bit?
The if statement is what I don't understand completely? Whats triggering the `if`? If the bit is greater then 0?

Because if mask is 1040, then really what were looking at is

```
if(1040 & 32768)    index 15
if(1040 & 16384)    index 14
if(1040 & 8192)     index 13
if(1040 & 4096)     index 12
if(1040 & 2048)     index 11
if(1040 & 1024)     index 10
if(1040 & 512)      and so on.....
if(1040 & 256)
```

I just really need to know whats triggering this if statement? i think i might be over thinking it, but is it simply trigger if the current bit is greater then 0?

The only other thing i can do is compile this source myself, insert printfs on key variables and go hand in hand with a hex editor and try and figure out whats actually going on here, if anyone could give me a hand would be awesome.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t  dest[1024 * 1024 * 4]; // holds the actual data

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fi, *fo;
    char fname[255];

    uint16_t mask, tmp, offset, length;
    uint16_t seq;
    uint32_t dptr, sptr;
    uint16_t l, ct;
    uint16_t t, s;
    int test_len;
    int t_length, t_off;


    // Print Usage if filename is missing
    if (argc<3) {
        printf("sld_unpack - Decompressor for .sld files ()\nsld_unpack <filename.sld> <filename.t2>\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    // Open .SLD-file
    if (!(fi = fopen(argv[1], "rb"))) {
        printf("Error opening %s\n", argv[1]);
        return(-1);
    }

    dptr = 0;

    fread((uint16_t*)&seq, 1, 2, fi); // read 1st 2 bytes in file
    test_len = ftell(fi);

    printf("[Main Header sequence: %d]\n 'offset' : %d \n", seq, test_len);
    sptr = 0;

    fread((uint16_t*)&seq, 1, 2, fi);



    while (!feof(fi)) { // while not at the end of the file set mask equal to sequence (first 2 bytes of header)
        mask = seq;
        // loop through 16 bit mask

        for (t = 0; t<16; t++) {
            if (mask & (1 << (15 - t))) { // check all bit fields and run AND check to if value greater then 0?

                test_len = ftell(fi);
                fread((uint16_t*)&seq, 1, 2, fi); // read 


                sptr = sptr + 2; // set from 0 to 2
                tmp = seq; // set tmp to sequence
                offset = ((uint32_t)tmp & 0x07ff) * 2; 


                length = ((tmp >> 11) & 0x1f) * 2; //  32 - 1?



                if (length>0) {

                    for (l = 0; l<length; l++) {
                        dest[dptr] = dest[dptr - offset];
                        dptr++;

                    }
                }
                else { // if length == 0 

                    t_length = ftell(fi);
                    fread((uint16_t*)&seq, 1, 2, fi);


                    sptr = sptr + 2;
                    length = seq * 2;

                    for (s = 0; s<length; s++) {
                        dest[dptr] = dest[dptr - offset];
                        dptr++;

                    }
                }
            }
            else { // if sequence AND returns 0 (or less)?

                fread((uint16_t*)&seq, 1, 2, fi);
                t_length = ftell(fi);

                sptr = sptr + 2;
                dest[dptr++] = seq & 0xff;
                dest[dptr++] = (seq >> 8) & 0xff;
            }
        }
        fread((uint16_t*)&seq, 1, 2, fi);

    }

    fclose(fi);

    sprintf(fname, "%s\0", argv[2]);

    if (!(fo = fopen(fname, "wb"))) { // if file 
        printf("Error creating %s\n", fname);
        return(-1);
    }

    fwrite((uint8_t*)&dest, 1, dptr, fo);


    fclose(fo);

    printf("Done.\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful here.

> `for arguments sake mask is 2 bytes 10 04, or 1040(decimal)`

That assumption may be nowhere close to true. You need to show how `mask` is defined, but generally a mask of bytes `10` (`00001010`) and `40` (`00101000`) is binary `101000101000` or decimal (`2600`) not quite 1040.

The general mask of `2600` decimal will match when `bits 4,6,10 & 12` are `set`. Remember a **bit mask** is nothing more than a number whose binary representation when `anded` or `ored` with a second number produces some desired result. Nothing magic about a **bit mask**, its just a number with the right bits set for your intended purpose.

When you `and` two numbers together and test, your are testing whether there are common bits set in both numbers. Using the `for` loop and `shift`, you are doing a bitwise test for which common bits are set. Using the `mask` of `2600` with the loop counter will test true when bits `4,6,10 & 12` are `set`. In other words when the test clause equals `8, 32, 512 or 2048`.

The following is a short example of what is happening in the `loop` and `if` statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* BUILD_64 */
#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_LP64)
# define BUILD_64   1
#endif

/* BITS_PER_LONG */
#ifdef BUILD_64
# define BITS_PER_LONG 64
#else
# define BITS_PER_LONG 32
#endif

/* CHAR_BIT */
#ifndef CHAR_BIT
# define CHAR_BIT  8
#endif

char *binpad (unsigned long n, size_t sz);

int main (void) {

    unsigned short t, mask;

    mask = (10 << 8) | 40;

    printf ("\n mask : %s  (%hu)\n\n",
            binpad (mask, sizeof mask * CHAR_BIT), mask);

    for (t = 0; t<16; t++)
        if (mask & (1 << (15 - t)))
            printf (" t %2hu : %s  (%hu)\n", t, 
                    binpad (mask & (1 << (15 - t)), sizeof mask * CHAR_BIT), 
                    mask & (1 << (15 - t)));


    return 0;
}

/** returns pointer to binary representation of 'n' zero padded to 'sz'.
 *  returns pointer to string contianing binary representation of
 *  unsigned 64-bit (or less ) value zero padded to 'sz' digits.
 */
char *binpad (unsigned long n, size_t sz)
{
    static char s[BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + BITS_PER_LONG;
    register size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        *--p = (n>>i & 1) ? '1' : '0';

    return p;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/bitmask1040

 mask : 0000101000101000  (2600)

 t  4 : 0000100000000000  (2048)
 t  6 : 0000001000000000  (512)
 t 10 : 0000000000100000  (32)
 t 12 : 0000000000001000  (8)
```

Comment: Thanks alot David, very informative answer, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> The if statement is what I don't understand completely? Whats triggering the if? If the bit is greater then 0? ... I just really need to know whats triggering this if statement? i think i might be over thinking it, but is it simply trigger if the current bit is greater then 0?

The C (and C++) if statement "triggers" when the conditional statement evaluates to true, which is any non-zero value; zero equates to false.

Straight C doesn't have a Boolean type, it just use the convention of zero (0) is false, and any other value is true.

```
if (mask & (1 << (15 - t))) {...}
```

is the same as

```
if ((mask & (1 << (15 - t))) != 0) {...}
```

The expression you gave is only true (non-zero) when there is a bit in the mask in the same position that the 1 was shifted by. i.e. is the 15th bit in the mask set, etc.

N.b.

```
mask & (1 << (15 - t))
```

<strike>can only ever be 0 or 1</strike> er... will only have one bit set.

Comment: Last sentence: No, it can be either 0 or `1 << (15 - t)`